# Error when trying to execute machine code

Tags: command-prompt, executable, machine-code

I am trying to learn at least how to make a hello world in machine code and understand it, but i can't find any hello world example that works, all examples gave me an error saying "16 bit application not supported"

i think the error is not with the examples because very few people use a 16 bit computer nowdays.

can someone show how to run an executable file to check if i am doing it correclty? (i am basically saving and typing     hello_world.exe     in the command prompt)

Comment: 16-bit programs cannot be executed directly on 64-bit operating system. You would have to install an emulating application, e.g. [DosBox](https://www.dosbox.com/). Or forget about 16 bits and try some [examples for Windows](https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#HelloWorld).

Comment: yeah but even if i make a random sequence of ones and zeros (such as 1101000011001001110101001100100100010011111101111100001010001101001001110011101100001111100010010100) the same error appears, and obviusly a random sequence is not always 16-bit

Comment: Are you saving random sequences to "hello_world.exe" and expecting it to work? Well, if you hire a troop of monkeys and let them repeat it for hundreds of years, it might happen to work, but that's not how programs are made. Create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and ask again.

Comment: no, i think you misunderstood me ;-; (and i cant create an example because i couldnt find any code that doesnt give me the error)